# factorial int value in C

Tags: c, factorial

so i've been recently doing a homeschool project in C. We were asked to make code which returns you the factorial of the number you put in. That's cool and simple, but we were also asked to make something, what will write you an error, if the number of factorial is higher value than the max value of integer.

```
int main() {
int a, i;
int faktorial = 1;
a = 10;


if (a < 0)
    printf("Chyba, faktorial z nekladneho cisla neexistuje. \n");
else {
    for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i) {
        faktorial *= i;
    }
    printf("Faktorial z %d = %d\n", a, faktorial);

}

return 0;
```

}

That's my code, which works perfectly, unless the value of factorial is bigger than the value of int. I've tried to make if statement, like if (faktorial > 2147483647) than printf error message, but it just didnt work and it still makes faktorial = 0.

Comment: You can check *before* the multiplication, for example `if(INT_MAX / i < faktorial) {/* will overflow */}`

Comment: Keep in mind that integer overflow in C produces undefined behavior, so you need to design your code so that you check whether each operation would overflow *before* you do it.  It won't work to compute first and then try to check whether you overflowed.

Comment: A 32-bit integer can store factorials up to 12!.  A 64-bit integer can store factorials up to 20!.  A 128-bit (unsigned) integer can store factorials up to 34!.  A 256-bit integer can store factorials up to 57!.  A 512-bit (unsigned) integer can store factorials up to 98!  You probably don't have a compiler that handles sizes bigger than 64-bit integers (though GCC has rudimentary support for 128-bit integers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't test if a factorial is greater than `INT_MAX` with `>` because an `int` will never be greater than `INT_MAX`. Instead, you can divide `INT_MAX` by `a` beforehand, and check if `faktorial` is ever greater than that. This is so you don't have to divide on every iteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
/* ... */
    int bound = INT_MAX / a;
    for (i = 1; i <= a; ++i) {
        if(faktorial > bound)
        {
            fputs("Integer Overflow!\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        faktorial *= i;
    }
```

Assuming `a` is strictly positive, this will always work.